# Getting No module name exifread error from QGIS Photo2Shape plugin?

Tags: qgis, exifread, photo2shape

I had Photo2Shape plugin installed on QGIS 2.4 (Windows 64 bit), following installation of 2.6.1 and an upgrade of the plugin itself Photo2Shape is now broken.

Error message on install is "No module named exifread".

I've done an uninstall of all versions of QGIS, deleted all User folders, and done a clean install of 2.6.1 thinking this would reset all my plugins but they're still there? And Photo2shape still not finding Exifread.

Comment: Solved by manually installing Exifread by following instructions at http://quantumofgis.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/qgis-standalone-and-python-modules.html.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows you do have to install ExifTools manually as mentioned in the other posts above. But I could not get it working without knowing where to install it to.

1. Download the python library from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead
2. Extract the folder "ExifRead-2.1.1" (the version number may vary) to any location on your harddrive. Although "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages" should be prefered.
3. In the folder "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages" (or any other folder that is configured within the QGIS python-path environement) add a new file "exiftools.pth" with just one line of text containing the path to the folder where you extracted the files at step 1 into. You may need admin privileges to do so. In my case that file would contain the following line:

C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ExifRead-2.1.1

4. Restart QGIS for an update of the pythonpath environement.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem after installing QGIS and photo2shape on my macbook OS X

To solve, simply download the exifread plugin

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead

Move ExifRead-2.0.2 to ~Library, Python, 2.7, site-packages 
Extract everything to site-packages (this is the only way I could get it to work, also took a screenshot of what is native to site-packages and stored it)

Then you will notice that the module loads but the points don't load as easily as they did in the previous version, I could only get mine to load by only selecting the final box.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said - this isn't an error - but perhaps a barrier to using Photo2shape.

If there are issues with installing ExifRead (I have some mostly connected to not understanding the instructions and organisational software policy) an alternative approach might be to use the older version of the plugin. I'm still on Photo2shape version 0.2.2 (QGIS 2.8.1, Windows) and it's working well. I've manually installed the plugin on another machine simply by copying the plugin sub-folder from my machine (and activating in the Plugin manager). Given that the plugin website is on Github I think it's presumably possible to use this to download the older version (sorry - no expert on Github).

[Update] See Bern V's comment below - the QGIS plugin manager allows installation of older versions of a plugin so my comments on Github can be disregarded....

Comment: Older versions of all plugins can be found at https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins. The plugin manager only downloads the latest release, but you always have the possibility to download older versions manually and extract the zip to your .qgis2/python/plugins folder. For Photo2shape, the path is https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/photo2shape/

Answer (score 2):

On OS X 10.11.1 and QGIS 2.12.0Lyon it is fast, and everything is ok, only on OS X 10.11.1 and QGIS 2.10.1Pisa the previous turn arounds don't help. After all the Instructions the Photo2Shape plugin was installed with an icon and the input window to choose the photo folder and the output shp. So this is no turn around, it is without any results! There may be a bug in this tool or installation.

The result of this tool converts gps data from photos to a sip file nothing else. A better and faster solution for this is to install exiftool and go on working. (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

1. Install exiftool
2. open the terminal
3. enter "exiftool directory -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -GPSImgDirection -T -n -r -csv out.csv" (the directory is your folder with photos inside)
4. you get the results in the terminal and as csv file.
5. open QGIS and import the CSV - the result is a point layer with the name of the photo and lat/long/direction.

so if there is a problem with installing the photo2shp plugin use exiftool.

Answer (score 1):

See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12002:

> Starting from 0.3.0 you need exifread Python module to use plugin.
>   This information also present in plugin metadata ("about" tag) and
>   should be visible in Plugin Manager and/or at the plugin page in
>   repository. exifread module available via PyPi
>   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead

Comment: Not really a bug though. You simply need another library to use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but if you have the OSGeo4W version, you open up the shell and type 

`pip install exifread`

Then reboot QGIS and install the plugin