# Installing exifread for QGIS photo2shape plugin for novice

Tags: qgis, photo2shape

I'm trying to install exifread so I can use the photo2shape QGIS plugin.

I know nothing about python and I haven't been able to get it to work using the answers from previous questions.

Can anyone please help with a set of clear step by step instructions for a novice?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  As it stands I think your question is too broad because I think it is asking for a new "dumbed down" version of existing documentation to be written.  I think you should list the exact steps that you have tried, from the documentation, and then let us know precisely where you are stuck.

Comment: This question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132697/getting-no-module-name-exifread-error-from-qgis-photo2shape-plugin?rq=1) has answers for installing exifread on Mac OSX and Windows.