# Install photo2shape

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation, photo2shape, exifread

I tried to use the photo2Shape plugin in QGIS ver. 2.12  . To be able to carry out photo2Shape plugin I must install ExifRead. How do I install ExifRead, so that the photoshape plugin can be active. I hope some one could help me.

Comment: This post might help: [Getting No module name exifread error from QGIS Photo2Shape plugin?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132697/getting-no-module-name-exifread-error-from-qgis-photo2shape-plugin).