# Installing photo to kmz error: no module named exifread

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to install plugins through the Plugin Manager v2.10 and am getting the error:

[image: install_error]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the **exiftool** dependencies for the plugin separately and then make sure the executables are on your PATH.

On Windows you need to install http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/

On Linux you need to install `libimage-exiftool-perl` or the Python package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead through pip.

There are other questions and [answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132697/getting-no-module-name-exifread-error-from-qgis-photo2shape-plugin) here that address the same issue for different plugins but all with the same dependency.

Answer (score 0):

There was a hangup on the plugin server lately.

You might need to click `Reload repository` at the bottom of the first form to get back to normality.